# Нужен код, который удаляет последние сообщение в отдельном чате дискорда

Tags: python, discord, бот, discord.py

По хорошему код должен начинаться

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я что-то не так понял, прокомментируйте своё сообщение, я попробую исправить ошибку. Вообще легче всего делать подобное с помощью команды.

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.channel.id == ид канала:
        await message.delete()
```